# Re-ordering columns in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df and a vector, x that contains the names of a subset of the columns of df. Is there a way in R to reorder the columns in df so that x appears before the other columns?

Answer (score 1):

We can concatenate the 'x' vector with the names of columns that do not belong to 'x' (`setdiff`))

```
df[c(x,setdiff(names(df), x))]
```